# Android AppCompat SupportActionBar - how to make icon auto-fit to a certain size

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

In my app, Icon will be loading dynamically and auto-fit in icon slot. Currently, the icon is not resizing, so it expand the height of `ActionBar`. I am using `SupportActionBar` instead of `ToolBar` because I just migrated from `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity` and wanted to reuse as much as possible. What can be done to make auto-fit an icon on the `ActionBar`?

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/root_view_second_screen"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   style="?wallpaper"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   tools:context="com.sarkms.cclib.SecondScreen" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/convView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
            android:transcriptMode="normal"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
        </ListView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_MultiContactsPing_note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/lightblue_rounded_poll_title_bg"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/lbl_multiplecontacts_ping_note"               
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_dark" />
    </RelativeLayout>        
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15sp" >

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/emoticon_btn"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/smiley" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/impMsg"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/imp_msg_unselected_5" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Send"
            android:src="@drawable/sendping_7"
            android:layout_width="35sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any problem of using `ToolBar` with `AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: It is setting the icon right in the middle, instead of making it left aligned. Plus, I will have to add the Toolbar to every layout xml. If I could achieve this resizing in SupportActionBar, I could avoid touching very layout xml.

Comment: Can you post your layout file, that include the icon and action bar ?

Comment: You can make separate file: like `tool_bar.xml` and call whereever you need:`<include @layout=tool_bar/>`

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. Can you help me set the logo as left aligned ? Right now, it is showing in the center of toolbar when I try it in a test app

Comment: Use `android:gravity="left"` for which logo do you want to be left.

Answer (score 0):

The information that you have provided is not sufficient to give any exact answer to your problem. But I suppose that you have one jpeg/png image that you want to fix into the icon slot.
One way to achieve is to convert that image into Bitmap and then adjust the height and width of the image.

```
Bitmap image =  //load image from your source
image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, iconSlotHeight, iconSlotWidth, true);
```

Now use this image bitmap to fill image into the icon slot.

Comment: Isn't there a way that it will auto-scale into the icon slot ? Like how it used to happen with the ActionBar ?

Comment: I don't know what used to happen with ActionBar. I think you need to adjust it according to the screen size. So, you can use `DisplayMetrices` to get the screen size and then manipulate the height and width according to your needs.